# How can I run binary files directly in windows?

Tags: binary, executable

I have a totally safe file that is a small executable program in the .out format. Being a windows user I was unable to run it, so I used a binary viewer software to open the file as pure binary code. I'm assuming I should be able to run it now, as binary code runs everywhere regardless of OS. I was just wondering how I could do this?

Answer (score 3):

If your executeable file is compiled and linked for windows, you need to rename it to: name.out -> name.exe or name.com depending on type of executeable.

Answer (score 0):

The binary file is so because it had been compiled by the respective compiler.  The human readable source code is compiled into binary or object code by the respective compiler.  Now you have viewed the object code through an object code viewer software.  You have viewed the object code of e.g., the  .py file. The binary file would be executable in the OS prompt if its extension filename is .exe, if it is an executable file, e.g., .py, then it's executable inside the Python compiler.  Convert the .py file to .exe file.  That .exe is runnable in the Windows, e.g., clicking it on the directory or at the C>, type the filename of the .exe file.  The .com is usually the external executable programs of the OS;  .bat - an executable file is for the batch files configured in the C>
If the .py file or .bas fo;e or .asm file or .prg file is already converted to .exe, create a shortcut for it so that an icon of it appears on the windows, e.g. Linux, MS